# Error in Python 3.4 calendar module

Tags: python, datetime

I am converting date strings from a file to datetime objects. The date string is 01122013, representing 1st Dec 2013. I am using Python 3.4 on Linux Mint 17.1.  It appears to me that the Python 3.4 calendar module has an error, (or I am doing something wrong), p.s. the code does work in a terminal with python 3.4.3.
My code snippet:

```
import datetime
...  # code to get the string
fmt = "%d%m%Y"  # ddmmyyyy
 result= datetime.datetime.strptime(mydatestring, fmt)
```

The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
File "/home/informatics/MyProgram/data_management.py", line 588, in load_monthly_update_data
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(mydatestring, fmt)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 273, in 
    _TimeRE_cache = TimeRE()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 190, in **init**
    self.locale_time = LocaleTime()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 73, in **init**
    self.__calc_weekday()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 93, in __calc_weekday
    a_weekday = [calendar.day_abbr[i].lower() for i in range(7)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/_strptime.py", line 93, in 
    a_weekday = [calendar.day_abbr[i].lower() for i in range(7)]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'day_abbr'

Comment: Could you add `import calendar; print(calendar.__file__)` right before your `result = datetime[etc]` line?

Comment: Yes, thanks. This then printed: /usr/lib/python3.4/calendar.py
Sorry for posting but I have discovered the error. - stupid me. I created another file called calendar.py which was imported in the main program.